# How can I fix my code to print a jSON syntax?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get the content of a jSON look alike page and print all the values, as you can see in my code below.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&year=2007&make=mini');

$vres = array('?({"Trims":' , '});');
$allakse = array("" , "");
$json = str_replace($vres, $allakse, $json);


echo $json;


$cars = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($cars[0] as $value)
{
    echo $value, "<br>";
}
```

this is how the file looks like.

```
?({
Trims: [
{
   "model_id":"15155"
  ,"model_make_id":"ford"
  ,"model_name":"Taurus"
  ,"model_trim":""
  ,"model_year":"2000"
  ,...(all available model fields are included)
 },
{
   "model_id":"15073"
  ,"model_make_id":"ford"
  ,"model_name":"Taurus"
  ,"model_trim":"3.0"
  ,"model_year":"2000"
  ,...(all available model fields are included)
  },
  {etc...}
]});
```

Even that I replaced some characters to make it look like a jSON syntax at the begining and end, I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the output what you are getting after running the script ?\

Comment: Do not try to create JSON by hand.  Create an array, then use `echo json_encode($yourData);`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat — The OP appears to be trying to parse third party broken JSON-P, not generate JSON of their own.

Comment: Prospective answerers should [read this possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22268923/472495) prior to answering, in case it is already answered there.

Answer (score 1):

The response is broken JSON-P, not JSON.

JSON-P consists of a function call (to a function name that you specify in the URL (`?` in this case)) with data passed via the first argument.

In JSON-P, that data is supposed to be JSON. In this case, it isn't. It is a JavaScript object literal that doesn't conform to the subset that matches the JSON spec. (Specifically, you have property names expressed as identifiers instead of string literals).

You could use a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) to identify the errors in the JSON response and try to clean them up (probably using some unholy set of regular expressions).

Alternatively, you could look at running a JavaScript engine (such as Node.js or Rhino), defining a function that passes the first argument to `JSON.stringify()`, then prints the result (and then capturing that back into a PHP variable).

---

Update:

I've looked at the URL you provided. The output does not match the data in the question. The JSON does appear to be valid and without the problems your code shows it to have.

Just stop asking for `callback=?` to get JSON instead of JSON-P. Then you don't need to strip off the JSON-P wrapper.

Comment: What if I remove the `"` from the properties and leave only the values with `"` ?

Comment: @Karoumpas — The problem is that the `"` are missing from the property!

Comment: Indeed, I see. I have updated my code and made it a valid jSON and managed to echo the values :) One problem though, it echos only the values of the first `{.....}` and does not continue to the others..

Comment: @Karoumpas: Because you are looping over `$cars[0]`.  Just get the JSON from `http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?cmd=getTrims&year=2007&make=mini`, decode it as-is with `$cars = json_decode($json, true);`, then do `foreach($cars['Trims'] as $car)`.

Comment: @Karoumpas: `$car` will be an array, so you need to get the properties of it (or loop over it).  It works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/mhB7cL

Comment: @RocketHazmat I see.. So there is not other way of having this without  adding the properties ?  I am asking because the source file contains json with fewer properties

Comment: @Karoumpas: I don't understand what your concern is.