# How to edit my code so that it will print all the blocks of a JSON string and not only the first?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get the contents of some source files from the same page and save them into MySQL. Some files have a different number of property names than the others so a more "auto" code will help. I am pasting below a sample source file, but you can see it live with my codes below.

**Sample source file:**

```
{
Trims: [
{
   "model_id":"15155"
  ,"model_make_id":"ford"
  ,"model_name":"Taurus"
  ,"model_trim":""
  ,"model_year":"2000"
  ,...(all available model fields are included)
 },
{
   "model_id":"15073"
  ,"model_make_id":"ford"
  ,"model_name":"Taurus"
  ,"model_trim":"3.0"
  ,"model_year":"2000"
  ,...(all available model fields are included)
  },
  {etc...}
}]}
```

**Expected output:**

I want to print the properties names just once because there are the same in number for all the source file.

```
model_id
model_make_id
model_name
model_trim
model_year
...and so on....

------
and afterwards all the values

15155
ford
Taurus

2000
...and so on...

15073
ford
Taurus
3.0
2000
...and so on...
```

**FIRST workaround attempt:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/dZDxoo

I can print the property names and the values. But with a problem. I need only one time the property names and this is ok. But it prints only the first block of VALUES and not the other VALUES. If I can print everything, this is my solution. The number of property names from different source files I am working, are different so this helps me to get the names automatically.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?cmd=getTrims&year=2007&make=mini');
$vres = array('{"Trims":' , '}]}');
$allakse = array("" , "}]");
$json = str_replace($vres, $allakse, $json);
$cars = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($cars[0] as $key => $car)
{
  echo "$key", "\n";
}

echo"<br><br>";

foreach ($cars[0] as $key => $car)
{
  echo "$car", "\n";
}
```

**SECOND workaround attempt:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/7bcDUx

Because the source files have a different number of properties, having a fixed `for each - echo loop` will not help me. This is essential because I want to get the property names automatically from each source file. Also, I can not print the properties names , just the values.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?cmd=getTrims&year=2007&make=mini');
$cars = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($cars['Trims'] as $car){
    echo $car['model_body'].'<br/>';
}
```

What should I do to echo all the values from all the blocks and not from the first only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix my code to print a JSON syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260805/how-can-i-fix-my-code-to-print-a-json-syntax). Please ask your questions only once, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your decoded json, you can just operate on the Array and print headers from the any item (lets choose the first item) and then print values from all items in the array:

```
<?php
function PrintFieldNames($item)
{
    foreach($item as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo($key . "<br/>");
    }
}

function PrintFieldValues($item)
{
    foreach($item as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo($value . "<br/>");
    }
}

$json = file_get_contents('http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?cmd=getTrims&year=2007&make=mini');
$cars = json_decode($json, true);
$cars = $cars['Trims'];

PrintFieldNames($cars[0]);
foreach($cars as $car)
{
    PrintFieldValues($car);
}
?>
```

Comment: This gives me an output of Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array

Comment: Does replacing `$cars = json_decode($json, true);` with `$cars = json_decode($json, true); $cars = $cars['Trims'];` make things better?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the change. Glad I could help you!